# fill + pattern on different paths vs. on the same path

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why does the following LaTeX manuscript

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=black]
  \path[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \path[pattern=bricks] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces red bricks:

[image: Red bricks]

whereas merging the two `\path` lines into one, as follows:

```
\path[fill=red, pattern=bricks] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
```

produces white bricks:

[image: White bricks]

?

Either the interior of the bricks in the brick pattern is transparent, or else it isn't. If it is transparent why doesn't the red fill show through in the second case? If it isn't transparent, why does the red fill show through in the first case?

Comment: As far as I can see you firstly print a red rectangle and set the (transparent) bricks on top of it. Secondly you set the bricks which take no fill option (RTFM Version 3.0.0 p 173).

Comment: @Jürgen is right, RTFM. page 171 states the difference between inherently colored and form-only patterns. The latter's colour can be changed (`[pattern color=<color>]`), the former can not. The bricks in the brick pattern are indeed transparent and only the lines making up the pattern can coloured.

Comment: @Jürgen: If the bricks are transparent, why doesn't the red fill shows through in the second case?

Comment: "The pattern works like a fill color. In particular, setting a new fill color will fill the path with a solid color once more." -- The Manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Then why does the red color shows through in the first case, as the second line should have overridden the first, no?

Comment: Ehm, no, they are two different paths. Your second case is sort of like saying `\path[fill=red,fill=blue]`, if I understand correctly. The pattern works like a fill, so it overrides the previous fill setting.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: So why doesn't the second path in the first example of my post override the first path? Just like `\path[fill=red]...;\path[fill=blue]...`?

Comment: (I'm confused by your confusion.) The brick pattern is transparent, or rather, it only draws the black lines, not the parts in between, so you see the red rectangle, *that is already in place* through it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Then why doesn't the red show through the transparent parts in the second example?

Comment: Because the `fill` isn't used at all.

Comment: Because that is how TikZ works. Sorry, I can't give a more in depth answer than that. Basically, if you have two `fill` settings in the same path, the latter one takes precedence, and the former isn't applied at all. I suppose the same thing happens with a `pattern`, it disables any previous `fill` settings in that `path`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case you have two different `\path`s, so the red rectangle is drawn first, and then the `pattern` is drawn on top. As the `pattern` only draws the black lines (it doesn't fill the parts between), you see the red below.

In the second case, because you add the `pattern` after the `fill` in the *same* `\path`, the `pattern` *replaces* the `fill`. The manual says

> The pattern works like a fill color. In particular, setting a new fill color will fill the path with a solid color once more.

so with `fill=red, pattern=bricks` the `fill` is ignored, and only the `pattern` is drawn. Similarly, if you swap the order (`pattern=bricks,fill=red`) only the `fill` is drawn.

If you want to do both in one path, you can use a `preaction` or a `postaction`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=black]
  \path[fill=red,postaction={pattern=bricks}] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

  \path[preaction={fill=blue},pattern=bricks] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sure there are several people around here who can give a more in-depth explanation of what happens, so please do that if you are so inclined.